# Scraping data and showing it in an ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webview

I'm creating a app where i'm scraping news and then showing them it an app. However i've experience some issues with news containing tables or other complex structure which is not possible to show in a ios application. There for i'm starting to think that it might be better just to create the news in html5 and then show them in a UIWebView. However how viable is this? or is there any better solutions for such?

Answer (score 0):

Create the news in html5 and then show them in a WebView: is good way ..  but you have to strong in html & javascript to handle scroll & contain display issue/ ready to compromise with image quality / know to handle java script call in native / can able to work on safari->develop-> debug .

Easy way : If you try in iOS you will find solution for complex structure display .

Comment: could you explain the easy way. How can i find a solution for handling tables and images inside the text using native?